# Java android - Ho do I set the background of an activity to camera preview?

Tags: android, background, camera

I'm very new to Java, and I'm trying to create an app where you can use the gyroscope to move an image on the screen, so that it looks like the image is sticked to an object in from the camera. The image is finished, and I got it moving, just like it should. Now I only need the camera as background of the xml file. Is there any simple ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout as parent layout of activity. Then place a Surfaceview to show a custom camera. Then you can place any layout on top of it to show other components. This is will look like a camera in background. For more info on placing camera on SufaceView, please check [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/camera-preview-on-surfaceview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to make the camera preview the first element in the first Layout object in the XML file.

You can use any of the Layout types based on how you would like to layout the other controls.  I used a RelativeLayout as the base for my layout here.  The FrameLayout with an id of 'camera_preview' is used as a container for the camera preview class.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".YourMainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <!-- ... other display controls ... -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in YourMainActivity's onCreate() create a new instance of your camera preview class and add it to the camera_preview container in your layout:

```
private static YourCameraPreviewClass mPreview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ... get camera instance ...

    mPreview = new YourCameraPreviewClass( this, cameraInstance );  
    FrameLayout previewFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById( R.id.camera_preview );
    previewFrameLayout.addView( mPreview );

    Log.d( LOGTAG, "Camera preview background set!  (:" );

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?